# ie9 & Firefox focus onmousedown input

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, focus, onmousedown

I have a web page that uses dragable elements to arrange applications to the users specifications. The user can drag(onmousedown) a box and drop it inline with other boxes.

Inside of those boxes are input, textarea, radio & checkbox types of input.

Everything works perfectly in IE8
Problems with IE9, Firefox 17.0.1 & Firefox 14.0.1(just the versions I've tested)

The problem is that when I click on an input box or a textarea box, the onmousedown event fires & steals the focus. Once I release the mouse, nothing happens to release the focus back to the input box. radio & checkboxes work just fine.

There are multiple inputs & multiple elements.

Anyonehave any ideas? I don't really have an open example to play with because it is in a login restricted environment.

I've been searching on this problem all day, any direction would be amazing!

```
function initdragableElements()
{
    dragableElementsParentBox = document.getElementById('dragableElementsParentBox');
    insertionMarkerDiv = document.getElementById('insertionMarker');
    insertionMarkerLine = document.getElementById('insertionMarkerLine');
    dragableAreaWidth = dragableElementsParentBox.offsetWidth;

    if(!useRectangle){
        dragDropMoveLayer = document.createElement('DIV');
        dragDropMoveLayer.id = 'dragDropMoveLayer';     
        document.body.appendChild(dragDropMoveLayer);   
    }

    var subDivs = dragableElementsParentBox.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var countEl = 0;
    for(var no=0;no<subDivs.length;no++){
        var attr = subDivs[no].getAttribute('dragableBox');
        if(opera)attr = subDivs[no].dragableBox;
        if(attr=='true'){
            subDivs[no].style.cursor='move';    
            subDivs[no].onmousedown = initDrag;

            var index = dragableObjectArray.length;
            dragableObjectArray[index] = new Array();
            ref = dragableObjectArray[index];
            ref['obj'] = subDivs[no];
            ref['width'] = subDivs[no].offsetWidth;
            ref['height'] = subDivs[no].offsetHeight;
            ref['left'] = getLeftPos(subDivs[no]);
            ref['top'] = getTopPos(subDivs[no]);
            ref['index'] = countEl;
            countEl++;
        }
    }

    /* Creating rectangel indicating where item will be dropped */
    rectangleDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
    rectangleDiv.id='rectangle';
    rectangleDiv.style.display='none';
    dragableElementsParentBox.appendChild(rectangleDiv);


    document.body.onmousemove = moveDragableElement;
    document.body.onmouseup = stop_dragDropElement;
    document.body.onselectstart = cancelSelectionEvent;
    document.body.ondragstart = cancelEvent;
    window.onresize = repositionDragObjectArray; 

    documentHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}

function initDrag(e)
{
    if(document.all)e = event;
    mouse_x = e.clientX;
    mouse_y = e.clientY;
    if(!documentScrollHeight)documentScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 100;
    el_x = getLeftPos(this)/1;
    el_y = getTopPos(this)/1;
    dragObject = this;
    if(useRectangle){
        rectangleDiv.style.width = this.clientWidth - (rectangleBorderWidth*2) +'px';
        rectangleDiv.style.height = this.clientHeight - (rectangleBorderWidth*2) +'px';
        rectangleDiv.className = this.className;
    }else{
        insertionMarkerLine.style.width = '6px';
    }
    dragDropTimer = 0;
    dragObjectNextObj = false;
    if(this.nextSibling){
        dragObjectNextObj = this.nextSibling;
        if(!dragObjectNextObj.tagName)dragObjectNextObj = dragObjectNextObj.nextSibling;
    }
    initDragTimer();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Back of my memory says something about a 'draggable' attribute for HTML5. Try looking that up, maybe.

Comment: Ironically enough, here is the answer

<div class="bigArticle" dragableBox="true" id="clientselect.php">
 <div class="clear" dragable="false">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
</div>

Comment: Solution above did NOT fully fix the problem, workaround is actually foolish, but it works: <input id="myid" onMouseUp="document.getElementById(this.id).focus();">